# phread_cond_broadcast race condition

Tags: multithreading, pthreads

I can't find a way to stop this race condition. The main thread calls the broadcast routine to wake up all the threads then calls a cond_wait to wait for all the threads to finish.  The last thread to finish signals the main thread.  The problem is sometimes not all the worker threads are waiting on the condition variable when the main thread does the broadcast. The code is a little messy because I was trying various fixes.

```
    unsigned nProcs, curProc;
    pthread_mutex_t WORKlock = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
    pthread_mutex_t MAINlock = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
    pthread_mute_t wj_varlock = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
    pthread_cond_t WORKsig = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
    pthread_cond_t MAINsig = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;

    void *do_work(void *t)
    {
    static unsigned offset = 0;
    unsigned myoff = offset++, locked = 0;
    volatile int nc;

    while(1)
            {
            if(locked == 0)
                    pthread_mutex_lock(&WORKlock);
            else
                    locked = 0;
            pthread_cond_wait(&WORKsig, &WORKlock);
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&WORKlock);
            // this is where the work gets done
            //sleep(1);
            printf("thread %d done!\n", myoff);

            pthread_mutex_lock(&wj_varlock);
            nc = --curProc;
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&wj_varlock);
            if(nc == 0)
                    {
                    pthread_mutex_lock(&WORKlock);
                    locked = 1;
                    pthread_cond_signal(&MAINsig);
                    }

            }
     }

    void main(int argc, char **argv)
    {
    unsigned i, k;
    pthread_t pth;

    nProcs = get_nprocs();  // get number of core from system
    for(i = 0; i < nProcs; ++i)
            {
            k = pthread_create(&pth, NULL, do_work, NULL);
            if(k != 0)
                    {
                    perror("pthread_create");
                    exit(k);
                    }
            }

    pthread_mutex_lock(&MAINlock);
    while(1)
            {
            //prepare work to be done

            puts("work prep");
            //sleep(1);

            curProc = nProcs; // use global var to track active threads
            pthread_cond_broadcast(&WORKsig);
            pthread_cond_wait(&MAINsig, &MAINlock);
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Condition variables need to be paired with a condition over some shared state (often called a "*predicate*") - that's why they're called condition variables.  So for example to start the workers you could use a simple global flag variable:

```
int start_work = 0;    /* Protected by WORKlock */
```

Then in the worker threads you'd do:

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&WORKlock);
while (!start_work)
    pthread_cond_wait(&WORKsig, &WORKlock);
pthread_mutex_unlock(&WORKlock);

/* this is where the work gets done */
```

And in the main thread you'd do:

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&WORKlock);
start_work = 1;
pthread_mutex_unlock(&WORKlock);
pthread_cond_broadcast(&WORKsig);
```

You can see that this way, if a worker thread hasn't blocked at the condition variable when the main thread does the signal, `start_work` will be 1, so it won't block at all.

To block the main thread until the workers are finished, you could use `curProc > 0` as the predicate.  Note that you don't need both `wj_varlock` and `MAINlock` - you just need one to protect the `curProc` variable.

(In order to make your design correct, you need to do some careful interleaving of the conditions on `curProc` and `start_work`)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int start_work = 0;    /* Protected by WORKlock */
unsigned curProc;      /* Protected by MAINlock */

pthread_mutex_t WORKlock = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_mutex_t MAINlock = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t WORKsig = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t MAINsig = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;


void *do_work(void *t)
{
    static int off;   /* Protected by WORKlock */
    int myoff;

    pthread_mutex_lock(&WORKlock);
    myoff = ++off;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&WORKlock);

    while (1)
    {
        /* Wait to start work */
        pthread_mutex_lock(&WORKlock);
        while (start_work == 0)
            pthread_cond_wait(&WORKsig, &WORKlock);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&WORKlock);

        /* Increase number of active processes */
        pthread_mutex_lock(&MAINlock);
        ++curProc;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&MAINlock);
        pthread_cond_signal(&MAINsig);

        /* this is where the work gets done */
        printf("Working (%d)...\n", myoff);
        sleep(1);

        /* Wait for all work to be done */
        pthread_mutex_lock(&WORKlock);
        while (start_work == 1)
            pthread_cond_wait(&WORKsig, &WORKlock);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&WORKlock);

        /* Reduce number of active processes */
        pthread_mutex_lock(&MAINlock);
        --curProc;
        if (curProc == 0)
            pthread_cond_signal(&MAINsig);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&MAINlock);
    }
}

int get_nprocs(void)
{
    return 8;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    unsigned i, k;
    pthread_t pth;

    unsigned nProcs = get_nprocs();  // get number of core from system
    for (i = 0; i < nProcs; ++i)
    {
        k = pthread_create(&pth, NULL, do_work, NULL);
        if (k != 0)
        {
            perror("pthread_create");
            exit(k);
        }
    }

    curProc = 0;
    while (1)
    {
        //prepare work to be done

        puts("work prep");
        //sleep(1);

        /* Tell threads to start work */
        pthread_mutex_lock(&WORKlock);
        start_work = 1;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&WORKlock);
        pthread_cond_broadcast(&WORKsig);

        /* Wait for threads to start */
        pthread_mutex_lock(&MAINlock);
        while (curProc < nProcs)
            pthread_cond_wait(&MAINsig, &MAINlock);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&MAINlock);

        /* Tell threads not to start next lot of work */
        pthread_mutex_lock(&WORKlock);
        start_work = 0;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&WORKlock);
        pthread_cond_broadcast(&WORKsig);

        /* Wait for threads to finish */
        pthread_mutex_lock(&MAINlock);
        while (curProc > 0)
            pthread_cond_wait(&MAINsig, &MAINlock);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&MAINlock);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Note that this kind of interlocked operation is more simply done with *barriers*:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>

pthread_mutex_t WORKlock = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_barrier_t WORKbarrier;

void *do_work(void *t)
{
    static int off;   /* Protected by WORKlock */
    int myoff;

    pthread_mutex_lock(&WORKlock);
    myoff = ++off;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&WORKlock);

    while (1)
    {
        /* Wait to start work */
        pthread_barrier_wait(&WORKbarrier);

        /* this is where the work gets done */
        printf("Working (%d)...\n", myoff);
        sleep(1);

        /* Wait for all work to be done */
        pthread_barrier_wait(&WORKbarrier);
    }
}

int get_nprocs(void)
{
    return 8;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    unsigned i, k;
    pthread_t pth;

    unsigned nProcs = get_nprocs();  // get number of core from system
    for (i = 0; i < nProcs; ++i)
    {
        k = pthread_create(&pth, NULL, do_work, NULL);
        if (k != 0)
        {
            perror("pthread_create");
            exit(k);
        }
    }

    pthread_barrier_init(&WORKbarrier, NULL, nProcs + 1);
    while (1)
    {
        //prepare work to be done

        puts("work prep");
        //sleep(1);

        /* Tell threads to start work */
        pthread_barrier_wait(&WORKbarrier);

        /* Wait for threads to finish */
        pthread_barrier_wait(&WORKbarrier);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I get the gist of it. Thanks!

Comment: Spoke too soon. Compiled your code and ran it. It gets stuck too. But your code sticks very quickly, mine will run hundreds of iterations. So I'm thinking I'll fix your code and apply the fixes to mine, if possible.

Comment: @BingBang: Yes, you're right - I've now added a debugged and tested version.  I've also added a version using pthread barriers which is simpler.

Comment: Well you taught me something new! I didn't know there was a barrier in pthreads! So cool! Thanks!